# Highlighting row by fetching database value

Tags: php, mysql

How can i Highlight employee table row ,by fetching `selected_val ==1` from the table `selected_candidate`, i want to highlight only those rows whose *`selected_val is 1`*
structure of *`selected_candidate`* table is

```
eid int(30)
rid int(30)
selected_val int(1)
```

I am using this query for displaying employee table on form

```
 $query = "SELECT eid,ename,lname,ecell,eposition,eemail,ecountry,estate,ecity,prefcities,ca,cs,cwa,completed,persuing,other_work1,other_work2,other_work3,other_work4,other_work5,other_work6,other_work7,other_work8,selected_val";   
                                $query .= "FROM employee INNER JOIN selected_candidate ON employee.eid = selected_candidate.eid";
     $query .= "WHERE efamiliar LIKE '%{$company}%' ";
```

*and this PHP code*

```
<?php

                                if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
                                {

                                //$url="down.php?location={$location}&status={$status}&company={$company}&qr={$qr}&flag={$flag}&count={$count}";
                                $i=0;
                while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
                                {
                $i=0;
                echo "<div id=\"Message1[$i]\" class=\"box\">";
                                        echo "Country ={$data_set['ecountry']}<br/>";
                                        echo "State = {$data_set['estate']}<br/>";
                                        echo "</div>";

                                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input id=\"select_candi{$i}\" onclick=\"javascript:func(this.id,{$_SESSION['uid']})\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_candi[]\" value=\"{$data_set['eid']}\"/></td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$data_set['ename']}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$data_set['lname']}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$data_set['ecell']}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$data_set['eposition']}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$data_set['eemail']}</td>";
                                 if($data_set['ecity']=='')
                                        {
                                        echo "<td>{$data_set['ecountry']}</td>";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        echo "<td onmouseover=\"ShowText('Message1[$i]'); return true;\" onmouseout=\"HideText('Message1[$i]'); return true;\" href=\"javascript:ShowText('Message1')\">{$data_set['ecity']}</td>";
                                        }

                               // echo "<td>{$data_set['ecountry']},{$data_set['estate']},{$data_set['ecity']}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$qua}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data_set['other_work1']} {$data_set['other_work2']}{$data_set['other_work3']}{$data_set['other_work4']} {$data_set['other_work5']} {$data_set['other_work6']} {$data_set['other_work7']} {$data_set['other_work8']} {$data_set['other_work9']} {$data_set['other_work10']}
                 {$data_set['other_work1e']} {$data_set['other_work2e']} {$data_set['other_work3e']} {$data_set['other_work4e']} {$data_set['other_work5e']} {$data_set['other_work6e']} {$data_set['other_work7e']} {$data_set['other_work8e']} {$data_set['other_work9e']} {$data_set['other_work10e']}
                </td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=\"detailcv.php?id={$data_set['eid']}\" target=\"_blank\"><input  style=\" cursor:hand;width:40px\" class=\"button\" name=\"cv\" type=\"button\" value=\"C V\" /></a></td>";               
                                echo "</tr>";

                                $i++;

                                }
                                }
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` the two tables, `Employee` and `selected_candidate`, like this:

```
SELECT 
  eid, ename, lname, ecell,
  eposition, eemail, ecountry, estate, 
  ecity, prefcities, ca, cs ,
  cwa, completed, persuing, other_work1, 
  other_work2, other_work3, other_work4,
  other_work5, other_work6, other_work7,
  other_work8,
  selected_val -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN selected_candidate ON employee.eid = selected_candidate.eid
WHERE efamiliar LIKE '%{$company}%';
```

then you can select the `selected_val`. Later, Using PHP from the front end application, you can test this value whether it is `== 1` or not, i.e., highlight it or not.

**Side note:** Your table this way, is not [**normalized**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You can move the `other_work`s columns into a new table, with a foreign key empid to that column.

Comment: it is giving me warning `at this line mysql_fetch_array($result_set)` not getting proper data

Comment: @raj - Can you please show me the exception you got, and the exact query you tried? thanks

Comment: I have edited query above as you have suggested ,and this is warning i am getting `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Comment: @raj You have to put spaces between the end of the line and the start of the next line. Please put spaces so that each word didn't stick into the first word in the next line. Also try to echo that query string before executing it and ensure it is working properly directly into MySQL.

Comment: @raj This warning is because there is a problem in your query, and it is not showing what is the problem please try to echo the query before executing it and paste it here and try to test it directly into my sql and show me the error you got.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22631/discussion-between-raj-and-mahmoud-gamal)